# Is there a 'complete' event on embedded facebook videos?

Tags: facebook, video, embed

I want to embed a facebook video in a webapp but do something when it's over.
Similarly to the YouTube API Player, is there any 'complete' event I can listen to on embedded FB videos?

Answer (score 0):

One solution/workaround a friend reminded me of is embedding the mp4 in jwplayer and hooking into the player's events API.

Sounds like it might work, but I would rather use a better solution is there is one.